# Communication between 2 different PC's with different IP addresses

Tags: networking

I am new to this networking domain.

I need to Implement one communication as described below.

I have 3 laptops, in that one laptop has both ethernet and wifi with different IP Addresses.

2nd laptop has Ethernet connected through LAN to 1st laptop.

3rd laptop has only wifi and 1st and 3rd both are in the same wifi network

1st laptop is like server and 2nd,3rd laptops both are clients.

Now I want to communicate 2nd and 3rd laptop directly with their IP address.

Note all these 3 laptops contains windows7/windows10

Laptop 1 has Ip address: for ethernet 30.0.0.16 and wifi 192.168.2.108

Laptop 2 has Ip Address: 30.0.0.17

Laptop 3 Has IP address: 192.168.2.186

please, anyone, have an idea about this type of communication please give me suggestions

Answer (score 2):

First of: Using 30.0.0.x for a private subnet is a bad idea if you want to experiment with networking, since according to Wikipedia the ip address range belong to United States Department of Defense.

It is better to stick to RFC1918 adresses. :-)

Those are:

```
10.0.0.0/8 (aka 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255)
172.16.0.0/12 (aka 172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255)
192.168.0.0/16 (aka 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255)
```

Anyhow:

In network terminology the proper word for `laptop 1` is that is a `gateway` or `router`.

The name of the game is routing is `laptop 1` hast route IP packages from `laptop 2` to `laptop 3` and vice versa.

The idea is that you tell `laptop 2` to use `laptop 1` ip address as its standard gateway.

Likewise: You tell `laptop 3` to use `laptop 1` as the standard gateway.

What you are telling laptop 2 and 3 is who should send the IP package to if it does not belong to the same subnet.

Laptop 1 job is to forward the IP package to the right subnet depending on what the routing table says on laptop 1.

Though you do need to setup 2 things on laptop 1:

- IP forwarding has to be enabled.
- The firewall on laptop 1 has to allow traffic from laptop 2 to laptop 3 and vice versa.

Comment: ok thank you How to enable IP forwarding in windows

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than on Linux, but there is a guide here: https://www.keepthetech.com/2016/01/enable-ip-routing-on-windows10.html/amp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider having a router to connect both networks, if you can't the only way I come up is by using the Server to route the packets with iptables  and using it as a gateway.

**Edited**
Considering that is using a windows server what you can do is set in  the clients the server as gateway. After that add static routing to the other network like this:

```
route ADD 192.168.2.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.2
route ADD 30.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 30.0.0.16
```

Then you can add a default gateway if you want that the clients can still access the internet:

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 GATEWAY_IP
```

Comment: I don't have any router.

Comment: and I am using Windows OS

Comment: @user549476 Is it a windows server or a windows client which gives a service?

Comment: thank you for your answer. now they want through socket programming means Laptop 1 is in server mode and laptop 2 and 3 are clients. by using socket programm laptop 1 will transfer packet by packet from laptop 2  to laptop 3 vice versa  is there any example code for this type communication

Comment: @user549476 the example already covers that scenario, unless you need a port traslation on the clients, also you should make sure the server have ip forwarding active as got suggested already.